# kafka dont work for me using for first time Connection refused .ZooKeeperClient

Tags: java, sockets, cmd, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka-streams

i Install kafka for first time.
i want to start it .
when i run  .\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
i get this result

```
[2021-10-08 10:03:43,563] INFO Socket error occurred: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181: Connection refused: no further information (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-10-08 10:03:44,693] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-10-08 10:03:46,743] INFO Socket error occurred: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181: Connection refused: no further information (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-10-08 10:03:47,873] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-10-08 10:03:49,928] INFO Socket error occurred: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181: Connection refused: no further information (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-10-08 10:03:51,043] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-10-08 10:03:53,093] INFO Socket error occurred: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181: Connection refused: no further information (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-10-08 10:03:54,233] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-10-08 10:03:56,283] INFO Socket error occurred: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181: Connection refused: no further information (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-10-08 10:03:57,403] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-10-08 10:03:59,443] INFO Socket error occurred: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181: Connection refused: no further information (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-10-08 10:03:59,523] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2021-10-08 10:03:59,683] INFO Session: 0x0 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-10-08 10:03:59,693] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-10-08 10:03:59,708] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2021-10-08 10:03:59,713] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:271)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:125)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1948)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.createZkClient$1(KafkaServer.scala:431)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:456)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:191)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2021-10-08 10:03:59,723] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-08 10:03:59,743] INFO App info kafka.server for 0 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-10-08 10:03:59,743] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-08 10:03:59,743] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.Kafka$)
[2021-10-08 10:03:59,752] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to start kafka

1. start zookeeper
2. start kafka server

Kafka server depends on zookeeper.
In order to learn the flow go through the below mentioned site,
https://www.javainuse.com/misc/apache-kafka-hello-world

Comment: i will try this thank you

Comment: i try agin and agin but the same problem

Comment: [2021-10-13 13:56:00,400] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)

Comment: [2021-10-13 13:56:00,413] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-10-13 13:56:00,414] INFO SASL config status: Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-10-13 13:56:02,461] WARN Session 0x0 for sever localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, Closing socket connection. Attempting reconnect except it is a SessionExpiredException. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information

Comment: ' ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)'

Comment: Please paste the error screenshot

Comment: it is  work for me the problem was in space in my disk C:/ .

Comment: He couldn't find enough space to write logs in directory